# JSON to Conll2003 conversion

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk, spacy

I am using a labeling tool that provides NER labels in the format of

[ "text": "I am a boy and I come from New York", labels [ {"start":20, "end":28, "label":"Location"}].

My models needs CONLL2003 format. Wondering if there are tools or scripts to do the conversion. So i can train Hugging face BERT NER model.

Thanks,